# Is it possible to download iTunes Extras?

Tags: itunes

I am going on a long flight and have purchased (and downloaded) some movies.

Is it possible to download all the iTunes Extras so that it can be viewed offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, iTunes Extras can only be watched while connected to the net.  It's not possible to download the Extras to watch without a connection.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203020

Comment: Appreciate your knowledge @fsb. Thanks. Although I wonder why then Apple lists iTunes Extras downloads in the Grid view. Quite confusing for the end-user.

Answer (score 1):

fsb is mostly correct: it is no longer possible/allowed to download iTunes Extras (as permanent files on your hard drive) for new purchases; you need to stream them over the internet.

However, that same article -- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203020 -- currently tells how to download iTunes Extras for purchases made before 10 July 2014:

> ### Download the original iTunes Extras
>
> If you bought a movie with iTunes Extras before July 10, 2014, you can download the original iTunes Extras on a Mac or PC with iTunes 9 or later using these steps:
>
> 1. Open iTunes and go to the iTunes Store.
> 2. Under the Quick Links section on the right side of the window, click Purchased.
> 3. Find the movie that you want to download, then click the Download  icon. You can choose to download the movie and its accompanying iTunes Extras. Or you can download only the iTunes Extras if the movie is already downloaded to your library.
>
> If you bought an HD movie before July 10, 2014, it might also have a streaming version of iTunes Extras. If it does, you can play it on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, Mac, PC, or Apple TV.